# How to set up Selenium WebDriver without using Maven?

Tags: java, ant, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am currently working on a very complex Selenium RC framework. It was set up before i got to use it by some other guy who is now not reachable. My plan is to upgrade to WebDriver. For this i will need to be able to use the old RC API, so i will use RemoteWebDriver. Is there any JAR that i can download that contains everything needed for my plan? And what if from now on the new tests that I will rite i want to use FireFoxDriver, IExplorerDriver and Chrome Driver? What are all the JARs that I need to download, where do i take them from and whow do I set them up correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I always refer to the google code page since i feel more comfortable with it, and also contains always the latest updates.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Copy-paste from the documentation:

**selenium-java-2.20.0.zip**    
 
The Java bindings for Selenium 2, including the WebDriver API and the Selenium RC clients. Download this if you plan on just using the client-side pieces of Selenium

**selenium-server-2.20.0.zip**
All variants of the Selenium Server: stand-alone, jar with dependencies and sources.

**EDIT**
Regarding how to set it up, if you are using eclipse 
*right click your project -> click properties -> java build path -> Add external jars*

Comment: To clarify, you would need only the selenium-server.2.20.jar file to move to webdriver.

Comment: Yes, the URL mentioned above is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be using WebDriverBackedSelenium to use goodies of both Selenium and webdriver. This may also reduce your time in upgradation. Sample code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.yoursite.com");
```

Best and official link to upgrade smoothly:  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.html

Comment: Yes, this approach is better to convert existing Selenium code to WebDriver (by using WebDriverBackedSelenium)